# запуск rest сервиса java

Tags: java, сервер, api, rest

Всем добрый день/вечер.Сразу говорю,что я на форумах впервые.У меня есть rest-сервис такого вида:

```
@Path("/")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserServiceAble {


@GET
@Path("/get")
public String getSelectedUserName(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    UsersDao dao = new HibernateUsersDaoImpl();

    String res = dao.find(id).getName();
    return res;
}
```

Вопрос:как его запустить на локальном сервере(localhost),или что для этого нужно.Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Поясните ситуацию. Откуда у Вас вообще взялся сервис? Да так, что не знаете что с ним делать?

Comment: Но как? Как можно взять и сразу писать без даже самого примитивного ознакомления с основами целевой платформы? Это же на первых строках любого учебника для начинающих написано. Возьми это, сделай так, потом сяк. Через это же в принципе нельзя перескочить?!! Т.е. дао, хибернат знаком, а сервер приложений нет? Десктопный программист что ли? Где этот сервис должен работать? Самостоятельное приложение или в составе (десктопной?) прораммки?

Comment: Только сегодня стал писать на вебе. Разбираться и смотреть видео-курсы нет времени(дедлайн поджимает).Если тебе не сложно,скажи плз как это делать)

Comment: Вот эти всякие штуки вроде рест, и пр. это из javaee. Предполагается, что это работает под управлением так называемых контейнеров - самостоятельных серверов приложений или встраиваемых в другие программы. Про встраиваемые ничего не скажу, А для самостоятельного потребуется какой-нибудь сервер приложений javaee full profile или web profile, в зависимости от задействованных возможностей. Их не трудно нагуглить, все они хорошо известны и имеют свои армии адептов. Готовое приложение в простейшем случае копируется в определённую папку и работает сразу же.